# Compare non English characters in string

Tags: javascript, node.js, string-matching

I need to compare non english strings as below

> Majsstärkelse  unicode -  `Majsst&#x00E4;rkelse`
>
> Majsstärkelse   unicode - `Majssta&#x0308;rkelse`

if I compare like this

```
if('Majsstärkelse' === 'Majsstärkelse')
```

Some of characters not working this comparison.So i tried with

```
const collator = new Intl.Collator('de')
const order = collator.compare('Ü', 'ß')
console.log(order)
```

But still no success result. How can I achieve this

Comment: `'Majsstärkelse' === 'Majsstärkelse'` works for me just fine both in the browser's console as well as in node.

Comment: @mapmalith did you read the entire comment ? see the last word there? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [String.protoype.normalize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) to normalize canonically equivalent strings.

```js
a='Majsst\u{00E4}rkelse'
b='Majssta\u{0308}rkelse'
console.log(a,b)
console.log(a === b)
console.log(a.normalize('NFC')===b.normalize('NFC'))
```

Note: the strings you have are escaped.  The above is for comparing unescaped strings.
Code to decode from unicode HTML entities first:

```js
const decodeUEntities = u=>u.replace(/&#(x[\dA-F]+|\d+);/g,
  (_,u)=>String.fromCodePoint(u[0]==='x'?parseInt(u.substr(1),16):+u))

str1 = decodeUEntities("Majsst&#x00E4;rkelse")
str2 = decodeUEntities("Majssta&#x0308;rkelse")

// decode unicode HTML entities, if you want named HTML entities too, find a list of them and add them to the replacement code, for simplicty I will be leaving that out
console.log(str1, str2, str1===str2)

console.log(str1.normalize('NFC'),str2.normalize('NFC'),
            str1.normalize('NFC')===str2.normalize('NFC'))
```